# C# Throwing inside infered Action makes it a Func when resolving overloads

Tags: c#, generics, exception, overloading, type-inference

I'm hitting a really annoying corner case of the type system.

I've reduced the code to the minimum requirements to show case the issue.

```
using System;

// Some interface or Base class, doesn't matter
public interface IFace {}
// Some class that implements/extends it
public class Implements: IFace {}

public static class Foo {

  public static void Bar<T, T1>(Func<T> f) where T1: IFace {
    Console.WriteLine("Bar relaxed");
    var _ = f();
  }

  public static void Bar<T1, T2>(Action f)
    where T1: IFace
    where T2: IFace
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Bar strict");
    f();
  }

  public static void Main() {
    try {
      Bar<Implements, Implements>(() => { // Should call Bar strict
        var _ = new Implements();
      });

      Bar<Implements, Implements>(() => { // Should still call Bar strict
        var _ = new Implements();
        throw new NullReferenceException(); // But having unconditional throw in the method
                                            // Makes it a `Func<T>` instead of a `Action`
      });
    } catch(Exception _) {}
  }
}
```

The output I want is

```
Bar strict
Bar strict
```

The output I get is

```
Bar strict
Bar relaxed
```

Repl: https://repl.it/repls/WearyImpoliteExponent

Can this be fixed? (Without deleting the first Bar, or changing the number of generic parameters)

*In the real code none of the `Bar` methods return void, they return things that reference the generic parameters, and their bodies are also different*

EDIT: To clarify, the "real world" `Bar` methods look more like this:

```
public static Baz<T, IFace> Bar<T, T1>(Func<T> f) where T1: IFace;

public static Baz<Default, IFace> Bar<T1, T2>(Action f)
  where T1: IFace
  where T2: IFace;

// Where `Default` is a concrete type
struct Default {}
```

The "real world" code: https://repl.it/repls/NaturalNoisyOpensoundsystem

Comment: Why do you need a `Func<T>`? What is `T`, is there any constraints?

Comment: Might be missing the point of the real world problem, but can't you just cast your parameter to `Action`?

Comment: I will try to clarify in an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. The trick is to add a `return;` after the thrown exception.

```
Foo.Bar<Implements, Implements>(() =>
{ // Should still call Bar strict
    var _ = new Implements();
    throw new NullReferenceException();
    return;
}
```

The lambda will now properly resolve as an `Action` instead of a `Func`.

The reason this happens is a pretty odd corner case in how overload resolution works. Essentially, if a lambda expression can be considered to be a `Func`, it will always be preferred over an `Action`. So long as all code paths return something compatible with your expected return type, the `Func` overload will be chosen. As you have zero returns, this condition is met, and the `Func` overload is used.

Comment: Hmm... I didn't want the responsibility to disambiguate to fall on the caller. But that explanation makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You could simply cast your argument as an `Action`

```
        Bar<Implements, Implements>((Action)(() =>
        { // Should still call Bar strict
            var _ = new Implements();
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        }));
```